How to show ongoing call timer in android status bar like whats app
I am developing VOIP calling application and I want to show timer on "status bar" for active ongoing call like whats app (highlighted in pink circle attached screenshot)

Does anyone know how to do that? I am using foreground service with notification for indicating ongoing active call.

We can do this using 'Notification.CallStyle.forOnGoingCall' (Android 12)

Android 12 adds the new notification style Notification.CallStyle for phone calls. Using this template lets your app indicate the importance of active calls by displaying a prominent chip that shows the time of the call in the status bar; the user can tap this chip to return to their call.

More info : New phone call notifications allowing for ranking importance of incoming calls
// Create a call style notification for an ongoing call.
Notification.Builder builder = Notification.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
.setSmallIcon(smallIcon)
.setStyle(
    Notification.CallStyle.forOnGoingCall(caller, hangupIntent))
.addPerson(second_caller);


What if I just want duration of OnGoing Call? Is there any way to get just duration in app screen?

@NipulRathod Could you elaborate on your query? (00:16) from the screenshot is the ongoing call duration. what do you mean by 'app screen', like  inside notification, App calling screen?

I want OnGoing call's duration in another screen not in notification or StatusBar. I mean when user call someone and call started then I want to show that duration in my app's screen.

Detailed explanation here.
Just replace the icon and Text with the call duration.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Foreground Service
class CallService : Service() {

private val CHANNEL_ID = "CallServiceChannel"
private var handler: Handler? = null
private var runnable: Runnable? = null
private var startTime: Long = 0

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    createNotificationChannel()
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
    handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
    runnable = Runnable { updateNotification() }
    handler?.postDelayed(runnable!!, 1000)
}

override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {
    val notification = createNotification("00:00")
    startForeground(1, notification)
    return START_NOT_STICKY
}

override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
    return null
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    handler?.removeCallbacks(runnable!!)
    super.onDestroy()
}

private fun createNotificationChannel() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        val serviceChannel = NotificationChannel(
            CHANNEL_ID,
            "Call Service Channel",
            NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
        )
        val manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager::class.java)
        manager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel)
    }
}

private fun createNotification(time: String): Notification {
    return NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
        .setContentTitle("Ongoing Call")
        .setContentText(time)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_call)
        .build()
}

private fun updateNotification() {
    val elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime
    val minutes = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(elapsedTime)
    val seconds = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(elapsedTime) % 60
    val time = String.format("%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds)

    val notification = createNotification(time)
    val notificationManager = getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
    notificationManager.notify(1, notification)

    handler?.postDelayed(runnable!!, 1000)
}

}
Now you have to call your this service from your activity and when the call ends you can stop it and register this service in AndroidManifest.xml
